# Submitting data from Infopath 2010 to SharePoint 2010?

Tags: document-library, infopath, column

I have published a Infopath form as Document Template of the document library, the Infopath form has so many fields(~200) however I would like to map few fields(~5) to SharePoint List columns on the library. Means that whenever the form is saved, it has to save the entire form in the document library along with the mapped column values.

Comment: Also would like to have a people picker control on the Infopath which should work like a people picker control in SharePoint..The idea is to map the infopath field to SharePoint site column..

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to Form Options -> Property Promotion
2. Add the fields you want to be promoted to the list.
3. Re-Publish the form.

[image]